# required_no_argument found string string string

Tags: android

My java file has an error in android studio Error is :-
When i try to run my app. i ogot this error that  error: constructor UserData in class UserData cannot be applied to given types

required: no arguments
found: String,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
  package Utility;

import android.content.Context;
import android.service.autofill.UserData;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.vision.join.RegisterActivity;

public class Firebase_method {

   FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   FirebaseDatabase mDatabase ;
   DatabaseReference mRefrence ;
   Context mContext;
   String userID;
   Integer gender ;

   public Firebase_method(Context context) {

       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       mContext = context;
       mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       mRefrence = mDatabase.getReference();
   }


   public void register_new_email(String strEmail, String strPassword) {
       mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(strEmail, strPassword)
               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                       if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ragistration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       } else {


                           userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                       }

                   }
               });


   }

       public void send_new_user_data(String name , String username , String email , String password){

           UserData userData = new UserData(name,username,email,password);
           mRefrence.child(userID).setValue(userData);

       }

}
```

My java file has an error in android studio Error is :-
When i try to run my app. i ogot this error that  error: constructor UserData in class UserData cannot be applied to given types

````
 



File UserData.java

package Model;

public class UserData {

 String name,email,username,password ;



 public UserData(String name, String username, String email, String password) {
     this.name = name;
     this.email = email;
     this.username = username;
     this.password = password;
 }




 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
     return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
 }

 public String getUsername() {
     return username;
 }

 public void setUsername(String username) {
     this.username = username;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "UserData{" +
             "name='" + name + '\'' +
             ", email='" + email + '\'' +
             ", username='" + username + '\'' +
             ", password='" + password + '\'' +
             '}';
 }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `Firebase_method` class you have a following line:

```
import android.service.autofill.UserData
```

That means that the `UserData` that you're referencing in your code is one that is already built in android. Instead, you need to use your own implementation.

So just delete this line and import `UserData` that is located inside your project in whatever folder you have and it should work just fine.

Comment: how to do this can you write what i have to write in my code .

Comment: @ItsAnonymousPlace go to your file where you have `UserData` class and at the top you will see something like `package com.example.application`. Copy that and post it here, then also check what is the name of the file where you have your `UserData` class and post it as well. After that I will tell what you have to add to your code so it works.